# Are streams closed automatically on error?

Tags: java, io

Hi all I understand that if we read bytes from an [InputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html) and we have finished reading all the bytes (or we do not intend to read to the end of stream), we must call [close()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#close%28%29) to release system resources associated with the stream.

Now I was wondering if I [read](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read%28%29) bytes and it throws a [java.io.IOException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/IOException.html), am I still required to call [close()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#close%28%29) to release system resources associated with the stream?

Or is it true that on errors, streams are closed automatically so we do not have to call [close()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#close%28%29) ?

Comment: Resources are closed when GCed.  SO you can have a problem which rarely throws an exception work ok.  For deterministic resource management, close() should always be called.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Are you saying that it is **because** the GC quietly eats the IOException thrown by `close()`  that we should call `close()` ourselves? So if (hypothetically) the interface of close() does not throw any form of Exception, we don't have to call close() when a stream has error?

Comment: That is something to consider, however its pretty common practice to ignore any exception thrown by close().  The problem with letting the GC do it is you could run our of file handles before you trigger a GC which cleans up these resources.  Your program can appear to work, but fail occasionally which is something you want to avoid.

Comment: @PeterLawrey I mean that was what I was asking, Will the file handle be released automatically when I call read() and it throws an IOException? (hence we do not have to call close()) .

Comment: it will automatically be closed by the GC if you don't close it yourself (the exception has nothing to do with it) This works provided you don't run out of resources before the GC runs.

Comment: @PeterLawrey However, I was wondering, Is the GC required to do so? Or rather, is it *guaranteed* that it will be automatically closed by the GC ?

Comment: It is guaranteed it will be close()d when the GC is run.  There is no guarantee if/when the GC will run.

Comment: @PeterLawrey I understand that java.lang.Runtime.getRuntime().gc() does not necessary release memory from discarded objects, However I was wondering Is the GC guaranteed to run (and close the stream) when we call gc()?

Comment: On the Oracle/Sun JVM it runs a full GC whenever you call System.gc(), unless you have used `-XX:+DisableExplicitGC`

Comment: @Pacerier Once again, it **might**, it's **not** guaranteed to and it frees memory on a best effort basis. You most probably don't need to use it, and if you find yourself using it, there might be a problem somewhere else.
Having said that, yeah, most JVM implementations will kick off a GC when you call it in practice, it's just that relying on it is not really all that safe...
P.S. It's the same as `System.gc()` and you can find **plenty** of threads on SO as to why it's damn bad practice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The OS itself **might** close the streams and deallocate resources because the process (namely, the JVM) terminates, but it is not mandated to do so.

You should always implement a `finally` block where you close it in cases like these, e.g. like this:

```
InputStream is = null;

try {
    is = new FileInputStream(new File("lolwtf"));
    //read stuff here
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println("omfg, it didn't work");
} finally {
    is.close();
}
```

This isn't really guaranteed to work if it threw in the first place, but you'll probably wanna terminate at that point anyway since your data source is probably messed up in some way. You can find out more info about it if you keep the `InputStream`'s provider around, like, if I kept a ref to the `File` object around in my example, I could check whether it exists etc via `File`'s interface, but that's specific to your particular data provider.

This tactic gets more useful with network sessions that throw, e.g., with Hibernate...

Comment: What do you mean by the last paragraph? Do you mean the tactic of *"implementing finally block"* ?

Comment: @Pacerier Meaning that it is pretty common to put, e.g., the closing of a Hibernate session in the finally block.